# Scatter Gather : Wait for all "Gather-Workers" to complete

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I am just getting into RabbitMQ.

I have a scatter and gather proof of concept working.

My eventual setup will be:

MyClient (aka, the Scatter'er)

MyGatherWorker1

MyGatherWorker2

MyGatherWorker3

MyGatherWorkerN (could go up to 10 at this point)

MyRabbitMQServerHost

MyGatherWorker1-MyGatherWorkerN will be wired up to the "Exchange" (I think that's the right term) on MyRabbitMQServerHost.

MyClient will send a scatter-gather request to MyRabbitMQServerHost.

Below is "MyClient" code.

I have a minResponses variable.  Which says "once I get N number of responses, consider the scatter and gather done".

**However, what is the best strategy for making sure all my configured "MyGatherWorker(s)" provide a response?**

I want to have a guaranteed "wait for all MyGatherWorkers" strategy.  And hopefully not where I have to put a "N" value on the client side configuration to match the (same) number of MyGatherWorker's.

I know I will eventually be adding more MyGatherWorker's to the system.

```
private ICollection<CustomerMoveSummary> SendScatterGatherMessageToQueues(List<string> customerIds, IModel model, TimeSpan timeout, string routingKey, int minResponses)
        {
            List<CustomerMoveSummary> returnItems = new List<CustomerMoveSummary>(); 

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_scatterGatherResponseQueue))
            {
                _scatterGatherResponseQueue = model.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
            }

            if (_scatterGatherConsumer == null)
            {
                _scatterGatherConsumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(model);
                model.BasicConsume(_scatterGatherResponseQueue, true, _scatterGatherConsumer);
            }

            string correlationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            IBasicProperties basicProperties = model.CreateBasicProperties();
            basicProperties.ReplyTo = _scatterGatherResponseQueue;
            basicProperties.CorrelationId = correlationId;


            String jsonified = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerIds);
            byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonified);

            model.BasicPublish(_scatterGatherExchange, routingKey, basicProperties, messageBytes);

            DateTime timeoutDate = DateTime.UtcNow + timeout;
            while (DateTime.UtcNow <= timeoutDate)
            {
                BasicDeliverEventArgs deliveryArguments;
                _scatterGatherConsumer.Queue.Dequeue(500, out deliveryArguments);
                if (deliveryArguments != null && deliveryArguments.BasicProperties != null
                    && deliveryArguments.BasicProperties.CorrelationId == correlationId)
                {
                    //string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(deliveryArguments.Body);

                    string returnSummaryJsonified = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(deliveryArguments.Body);
                    CustomerMoveSummary summary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerMoveSummary>(returnSummaryJsonified);

                    returnItems.Add(summary);
                    if (returnItems.Count >= minResponses)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("returnItems.Count >= minResponses !!");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return returnItems;
        }
```

PS

If anyone has any "an exception occurred on the MyGatherWorker", what's the best practice for handling that?

Comment: That was my first comment, that it was duplicate.  "I just said that, yo"  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqXB8NVLlII#t=4

Comment: StackOverflow seems to like to post comments on my behalf on a post when I raise a helpful flag to let them know they should link the thread to another one...hmm...contrary to what I thought. This is my mistake.